# "I worked the whole day yesterday" vs "I was working the whole day yesterday"

Tags: difference, past-simple, past-continuous

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> I wasn't at Julie's birthday, because **I** **worked** the whole day yesterday.
>
> I wasn't at Julie's birthday, because **I was** **working** the whole day yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

These both mean the same, generally, but would normally be used in response to different situations.

If someone asked about the total amount of time you were doing something:

> How much do we owe you?
> *Well,* ***I worked*** *the whole day yesterday.*

If someone wanted to confirm your location at a certain time:

> Where were you yesterday afternoon?
> *Well,* ***I was working*** *the whole day yesterday.*